# fix Combobox searchable error run time 70

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I wrote a combobox searchable. However, I got an run time error '70': permission denied.  Please, help me!

[image]

```
Private Sub cmb_phanloaitheomucdo_12_Change()
    Dim i As Long
    If Not Comb_Arrow Then
        With Me.cmb_phanloaitheomucdo_12
            .List = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheet1.Range("B2"), Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value
            .ListRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(4, .ListCount)
            .DropDown
            If Len(.text) Then
                For i = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
                    If InStr(1, .List(i), .text, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then .RemoveItem i
                Next
                .DropDown
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmb_phanloaitheomucdo_12_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then Me.txt_phanloaieau_13.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: see [permission denied error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/permission-denied-error-70)

Comment: nah.  it doesn't help me

Answer (score 0):

If the `RowSource` property of a combobox control is in use, attempting to set the `List` property will trigger a runtime error 70.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Me.ComboBox1.List = Range("D1:E3").Value
End Sub
```

To resolve this issue, add a line of code to reset the `RowSource` property before setting the `List` property or make the necessary adjustments in VBE.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Me.ComboBox1.RowSource = ""
    Me.ComboBox1.List = Range("D1:E3").Value
End Sub
```

[image]